# Grails retrieve custom query to Mapped List

Tags: java, grails

i'm new in grails...

I want to create a Controller for my jquery autocomplete

```
def arrSong = Song.executeQuery("select id, title as value, concat(artist, ' - ', title) as label from ${Song.name} where title like concat('%', :paramTitle, '%')", [paramTitle:params.term?.toString()])
render arrSong as JSON
```

with this code i get this JSON :

```
[[1,"Mr. Brightside","The Killers - Mr. Brightside"]]
```

my expectation is like :

```
[{"id":1,"value":"Mr. Brightside","label":"The Killers - Mr. Brightside"}]
```

anyone can help ?

Comment: Have a look for ajaxdependancyselection plugin. It provides auto complete functionality from gsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executeQuery` the way you have written would return a list of unnamed results which has to be retrieved by using the index.

For example:

```
[[1,"Mr. Brightside","The Killers - Mr. Brightside"]]

arrSong.each{println it[0]} 
//Prints 1, similarly it[1] for "Mr. Brightside" and so on
```

What you need is a `map` representation of your result set as below, then you should be able to render the map effortlessly as a JSON.

```
def query = """
             select new map(id as id, 
                            title as value, 
                            concat(artist, ' - ', title) as label) 
             from ${Song.name} 
             where title like concat('%', :paramTitle, '%')
            """

def arrSong = Song.executeQuery(query, [paramTitle: params.term?.toString()])

render arrSong as JSON
```

should return

```
[{"id":1,"value":"Mr. Brightside","label":"The Killers - Mr. Brightside"}]
```