# Restrict the scope of data when using withCriteria

Tags: json, hibernate, grails, groovy

I currently have the following 3 domain classes :

User.groovy

```
class User {
    ...

    static hasMany = [
        ...
        ]

    static belongsTo = [        
        course : Course,
        university : University     
        ]

}
```

Course.groovy

```
class Course {

    String title

    static hasMany = [
        universities : University, 
        users : User
        ]

    static belongsTo = University       

}
```

University.groovy

```
class University {

    String name

    static hasMany = [
        courses : Course,
        users : User
        ]           
}
```

I gather all of the courses for a university with the following code :

```
def courses = Course.withCriteria {      
          universities {
            eq('id', Long.parseLong(params.universityId))
          }
        }
        render courses as JSON
```

With an example response like so :

```
[{
            "class":"classifieds.Course",
            "id":1,
            "title":"Computer Science",
            "universities":
                [{"class":"University",
                    "id":1}],
            "users":
                [{"class":"User"
                    ,"id":1}]
        }]
```

My issue is that I want to restrict the scope of the response to not include the `users`  or `universities`that are currently being returned, I only what a list of `courses` to be returned in the JSON. How to I restrict this?

Comment: `University.get( params.long( 'universityId' ) ).courses.title as JSON`?

Comment: thanks for that - close.. Is it possible to get the `course` back with an `id` aswell so the response would be a collection of `{"id":1,"title":"Computer Science"}` etc?

Comment: `University.get( params.long( 'universityId' ) ).courses.collect { [ id: it.id, title: it.title ] } as JSON`? ;-)

Comment: There's probably a more efficient way to get the same result however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your desired JSON Object marshaller for `Course` in bootstrap as below:

```
//Bootstrap
def init = { servletContext ->
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Course){
        def returnObj = [:]
        returnObj.id = it.id
        returnObj.title = it.title

        returnObj
    }
}
```

The above registers to only return the fields of `Course` when converted and rendered to JSON. Note this is going to permanently marshal Course to only return its fields and not its associations. If needed temporarily then you can very well follow Tim's approach.

In case you want to make it generic for the all the fields, then:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Course){course ->
    def fields = grailsApplication.domainClasses
                                  .find{it.name == 'Course'}
                                  .properties
                                  .findAll{!it.association}
                                  .name - 'version' //Remove version if req.

    return fields.collectEntries{[it, course."$it"]}
}
```

provided `grailsApplication` is injected to `Bootstrap.groovy`

To add, if the intention is not to modify the way JSON is built but to reconcile the criteria result then use `projections` to get the required `property`:

```
def courses = Course.withCriteria {      
   universities {
     eq('id', Long.parseLong(params.universityId))
   }
   projections{
      property('id')
      property('title')
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
In order to retrieve results as mapped entities then I would follow HQL as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19079733/2051952) or use `createCriteria` and transform the result to map as below (untested):

```
import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers

def criteria = Course.createCriteria()
criteria.resultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
def courses = criteria.list {      
   universities {
     eq('id', Long.parseLong(params.universityId))
   }
   projections{
      property('id')
      property('title')
   }
}
```

I am not sure aliases will be created by the property names. I you face any issue, you can swiftly fallback to HQL query.

Comment: I like the idea of using `projections` when I tried it however with what you have above, the response format seems to be different to a normal JSON response.  It is along the lines of `([1:Computer Science],[2:Physics])` rather than `{{"id":1,"title":"Computer Science"},{"id":2,"title":"Physics"}}`

Comment: Try using HQL or `createCriteria`. See my update. @andymccullough