# Grails Domain Object Includes Class Attribute

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm using a domain object to interface with a database in Grails.

When I use the list() method on a domain object to get all of the rows from a database it works great except for one thing.  The object that comes back for each row also includes an attribute called "class".  I've read some things about creating a custom marshaller that would allow me to remove that attribute from the object.  Is that really the best way to not have to return the class attribute?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing the class in the actual database record or are you talking about when you render it as JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to change the way Grails renders JSON by default:
http://grails.org/doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#defaultRenderers

Just change "NameOfDomainClass" to the class you want to render differently.  In this case, the Domain Class.

```
import grails.rest.render.json.*
beans = {
    bookRenderer(JsonRenderer, NameOfClass) {
        excludes = ['class']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`JSON.registerObjectMarshaller`](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/api/grails/converters/JSON.html#registerObjectMarshaller(Class%3C?%3E,%20Closure%3C?%3E)) as below:

```
// BootStrap.groovy
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller( YourDomain ) {
    it.properties.findAll { it.name != 'class' }
}
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082572/restrict-the-scope-of-data-when-using-withcriteria/19084890#19084890) for a similar example.