# Is there any way to return a Map with some fields from a createCriteria in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an object where I need to query and return it as a Map, but I don't want to iterate over the object again as I'm already doing a query and it can get a bad performance.

```
List<MyObject> myObjectList = MyObject.createCriteria().list(params) {
...
}
```

But what I need is a Map like:

```
myObjectList.each { MyObjectList myObject ->
   myMap.add([person: myObject.person, myObject: myObject, listIntoObject: myObject.listInsideObject as List])
}
```

I found another way to get a map like this but it still not the better way to get a Map from a List that I'm querying with GORM...

```
myMap = myObjectList.collect{ [person: it.person, myObject: it, listIntoObject : it.invoiceDetails as List] }
```

Is there a better way to get a Map using GORM?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `org.hibernate.transform.Transformers` to transform the result to an entity map

```
import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers

def criteria = MyObject.createCriteria()
criteria.resultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)

def myObjectList = criteria.list(params) {
    ...
}
```

You can also fall back to HQL as well. Refer the **UPDATE** section of [a similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082572/restrict-the-scope-of-data-when-using-withcriteria/19084890#19084890) answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification` with `withCriteria()` to transform the result in a Collection object, with properties chosen by you only:

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification

def criteria = User.withCriteria(){
    resultTransformer CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP
    createAlias 'personalData', 'p'
    eq 'id', params.id
    // ...and so on, then
    projections {
        property 'id', 'myId' // a property called 'myId', from User
        property 'p.name', 'userName' // from personalData, a property mapped by a fk in User
        property 'p.age', 'age'
    }
}
```